# Spring Batch + iBatis + Multiple Data source configuration

Tags: spring, spring-batch, ibatis

I have Spring batch and I have written Cron Job. Job will fetch data from Datasource 1 and will store that data in the tables from Datasource 2.

I have iBatis, How should I configure that?

Thanks,

Jay Patel

Comment: For the record, the iBatis based ItemReader from Spring Batch is depricated in favor of the one provided by the MyBatis project.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch offers out-of-the-box reader and writer for iBatis :

- `IbatisPagingItemReader` : [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/IbatisPagingItemReader.html)
- `IbatisBatchItemWriter` : [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/IbatisBatchItemWriter.html)

Examples :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.IbatisPagingItemReader">
    <property name="queryId" ref="query" />
    <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <property name="pageSize" value="1000"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.IbatisBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient" />
    <property name="statementId" ref="query" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have multiple queries for reading and same for writing.. Can I provide that?

Comment: @JayPatel These reader and writer can be duplicated in separate steps. You can also create an abstract step (Documentation §5.1.2) to factorize declarations, leaving only the query and mapping to be implemented.